# How to implement a partially flexible screen layout with a grid framework?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

I am trying to implement the following screen layout using a CSS grid framework (BluePrint), but unsuccessfully:

[image]

How can achieve this with a grid framework? Does anyone have a CSS/HTML code example to share? Thanks.

**P.S.:** The reason I want to use a framework is to make sure this layout works in all browsers (any *safe* framework is ok, it does not have to be BluePrint).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deep into this issue, I got to understand that it is impossible to solve it with a grid framework. The problem is that a couple of heights and widths are derivative of each other. Moreover, depending on the content of the 'central' cell, slide bars may appear too.

I found a long solution involving some Javascript. I first define the different cells of my screen with divs in my HTML. Then, I retrieve the document width and height and set cells' widths and heights using JQuery. I start with fix values, then simple derivatives, then complex derivatives.

For the slide bar issue, I used the trick explained [here](http://jdsharp.us/jQuery/minute/calculate-scrollbar-width.php). I adjust the size of the central column according to the presence of a slide bar, which itself is depending on the height of the 'central' cell, which itself depends on the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

YAML should be able to that: http://www.yaml.de/fileadmin/examples/04_layouts_styling/3col_faux_columns.html

or maybe Fluid 960? 
http://designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

Comment: Thanks. I did try with both, but after getting into details, I got to understand that solving my issue with a grid framework is in fact impossible. I'll explain in the answer I am about to create.